# Issues loading Bootstrap styles in javascript created table

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am creating a trivia game pulling questions from an API. I want to style the game with bootstrap. The game is an HTML table created with Jquery in Javascript. The table appends onto the page after the function is called, but it does not look like the bootstrap design. It appears that bootstrap isn't loading correctly?

I tried including the CDN Bootstrap link at the bottom of the HTML page, but no luck. I also tried copy pasting the HTML from Javascript onto the HTML page, but still doesn't style correctly. I am running out of ideas on how to approach this. Any help is appreciated!

The table style I desire is the dark bordered one on the bootstrap webpage: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/#bordered-table

```js
let categories = [];
let catsAndClues = [];

// create Jeopardy Title and Start/Reset button
$("body").append(`
    <h1 id="title">JEOPARDY!</h1>
    <div id="button-div">
        <button id="button" data-startBtn="true">Start!</button>
    </div>
    <div id="game-board">
    </div>`)

async function getCategoryIds() {
    // save random number from one to 18000 to randomInt
    // randomInt will be used as the "offset" parameter to get a random sequence of categories
    let randomInt = Math.floor((Math.random() * 18000) + 1);
    let res = await axios.get(`http://jservice.io/api/categories?count=100&offset=${randomInt}`);
    // create a loop to iterate until the categories array contains 6 items
    for (let i=0;categories.length<6;i++){
        // pull random ID number from the 100 categories pulled from API
        let i= Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        let randomCatId= res.data[i].id;
        // if categories array does not include the randomCatId, add it to the categories array
        if (!categories.includes(randomCatId)){
            categories.push(randomCatId);
        }
        console.log(categories);
    }
}

async function getCategory(catId) {
    // retreive clues from API with the category ID parameter
    let res = await axios.get(`http://jservice.io/api/clues?category=${catId}`);
    // use .map function to return object displaying question, answer, and "showing"
    // properties for every item in the data's array
    let clueGroup = res.data.map(clue => {
        return {
          question: clue.question,
          answer: clue.answer,
          showing: null,
        };
    })
    console.log("clueGroup:", clueGroup);
    let clueArray = [];
    for (let i=0;clueArray.length<5;i++){
        // pull random clue from the clues array and save to variable
        let i= Math.floor((Math.random() * clueGroup.length));
        let randomClue= clueGroup[i];
        // if categories array does not include the randomCatId, add it to the categories array
        if (!clueArray.includes(randomClue)){
            clueArray.push(randomClue);
        }
    };
    // define obj to show category title and list of all clues within the category
    console.log("clueArray: ", clueArray);
    console.log(res.data[0].category.title);
    return {title: res.data[0].category.title, clues: clueArray};
}


function fillTable() {
    $("#game-board").append(
        `<table>
        <thead>
            <tr id="header-row" class="table table-dark">
                <th scope="col">${catsAndClues[0].title}</th>
                <th scope="col">${catsAndClues[1].title}</th>
                <th scope="col">${catsAndClues[2].title}</th>
                <th scope="col">${catsAndClues[3].title}</th>
                <th scope="col">${catsAndClues[4].title}</th>
                <th scope="col">${catsAndClues[5].title}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[0].clues[0].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[1].clues[0].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[2].clues[0].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[3].clues[0].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[4].clues[0].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[5].clues[0].question}">?</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[0].clues[1].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[1].clues[1].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[2].clues[1].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[3].clues[1].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[4].clues[1].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[5].clues[1].question}">?</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[0].clues[2].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[1].clues[2].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[2].clues[2].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[3].clues[2].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[4].clues[2].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[5].clues[2].question}">?</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[0].clues[3].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[1].clues[3].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[2].clues[3].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[3].clues[3].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[4].clues[3].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[5].clues[3].question}">?</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[0].clues[4].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[1].clues[4].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[2].clues[4].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[3].clues[4].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[4].clues[4].question}">?</th>
                <th id="${catsAndClues[5].clues[4].question}">?</th>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>`);

}


async function setupAndStart() {
    await getCategoryIds();
    console.log(catsAndClues);
    for (let i=0;catsAndClues.length<6;i++){
        let tempVar = await getCategory(categories[i]);
        catsAndClues[i] = tempVar;
    }
    console.log(catsAndClues);
    fillTable();

}
setupAndStart()
```

```css
/* some colors you may find useful:
  #115ff4
  #060ce9
  #28a200
  #8d2ab5
  #74119c
*/

body {
  background-color:  #115ff4;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f2dc56;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px black;
  font-size: 3em;
}

#button-div{
  text-align: center;
}

#button{
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Copse&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jeopardy.css">
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash"></script>
<script src="jeopardy.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you forget to add classes like bootstrap have to your `table` in the `fillTable()` function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add classes to the table tag "table table-bordered table-dark"

Comment: You can copy the code snippet in the question to your answer and modify it to make your answer more useful :)